# Getting rows of data frame excluding header in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file of which the screenshot is shown below :
[image]
**My goal is to get the rows of the data frame excluding the header part.**

My Purpose: I'm converting data in row into **"float64"** using the function **astype()** and then rounding the data to two decimal point using pandas **round()** function. The code for the same is shown below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/viral/PycharmProjects/Samples/036_20191009T132130.CSV',skiprows = 1)
df = df.astype('float64', errors="ignore")
df = df.round(decimals=2)
```

Here as you can see that I'm Skipping the first row in order to exclude the header part.

But Unfortunately, the data is not rounding up to 2 decimals place. The results are shown below :
[image]

I am not sure, but I guess the line **Empty Data frame** is making a problem in rounding up the data.

**With Header= None**
[image]

Even header= 1 will act in the same way the skiprow=1 was acting.

Any suggestions are most welcome...

Thank you

Comment: skipping first row makes your file have no rows. instead using `skiprows`  use `header=None`

Comment: @Tserenjamts header = None will give number 0,1,2 above the actual header.

Comment: I would suggest just remove the `skiprows` and execute your code. header=None might not be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
file = 'C:/Users/viral/PycharmProjects/Samples/036_20191009T132130.CSV'

#for default columns 0,1,2, N with omit first row in original data
df = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows = 1, header=None)
#for columns names by first row in file omit skiprows and header parameters
#df = pd.read_csv(file)
#if necessary, convert to floats
df = df.astype('float64', errors="ignore")
#select only numeric columns
cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
#round only numeric cols
df[cols] = df[cols].round(decimals=2)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to skip those columns number 0,1,2, N and only get the data ?

Comment: @ViralParmar - OK, why this is necessary? Do you need write to file with no header? Or only want display it?

Comment: I want to display it in QTableWidget. When I m trying to display it, it is showing blank line in QTableWidget and then the actual data.

Comment: @ViralParmar -  Is possible pass `df.values` instead `df` ?

Comment: I am Emitting a copy of data frame "self._emitter.newDataFrameSignal.emit(df.copy())" instead i should do "self._emitter.newDataFrameSignal.emit(df.values)"?

Comment: Well, the problem is the Pyqt Slot is only taking the data frame as the argument. Showing Error when I pass Numpy array ( df.values). Do you have any alternate suggestion of passing dataframe only.

Comment: @ViralParmar - hmm, it is problem, because in pandas dataframe MUST contains columns, here is a bit uggly trick - set them to empty spaces `df.columns = [''] * len(df.columns)`

Comment: Well, the trick is really good, but I don't understand why I am getting a blank row before displaying actual data.

Comment: @ViralParmar - hmmm, it is uggly trick, so not working :( DataFrame with no columns names is not DataFrame, so if not possible pass another structure of data like array or list (where are not columns) then it is problem. Maybe is possible some trick in `QTableWidget` side, but never working with it, so not idea :(

Comment: do you think that pd.set_option("precision", 2 ) will work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/viral/PycharmProjects/Samples/036_20191009T132130.CSV',skiprows = 1)
df = df.astype('float64', errors="ignore")
df = df.round(decimals=2)
```

Comment: header = None will give number 0,1,2 above the actual header.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: Let me Edit my Post with your Suggestion.

Comment: Please Check the Edited post